# Saripaar validation Android, multiple forms

Tags: android, forms, validation, saripaar

I have 3 forms in a same activity (and layout) that I want validate using saripaar. This validates the three forms, but they dont validate independently.

This the layout:

- Form1: Input for email and submit button.
- Form2: Input for a validation code and submit button.
- Form3: Input for a password, passwordconfirm and submit button.

I want that when you press submit for form1, validate only the rules form the form1, and same to form2 and form3.

I have 3 validators objects and the logic of each of them is similar. Ex:

```
validatorEmail = new Validator(this);
editTextRecoveryEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRecoveryEmail);
buttonRecoveryEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecoveryEmail);

validatorEmail.setValidationListener(new ValidationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValidationSucceeded() {
                // Enviar el email
            }

            @Override
            public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
                String message = failedRule.getFailureMessage();
                if (failedView instanceof EditText) {
                    if (failedView.getId() == editTextRecoveryEmail.getId()) {
                        failedView.requestFocus();
                        ((EditText) failedView).setError(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

buttonRecoveryEmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validatorEmail.validate();
            }

        });
```

This my full activity code:

```
/* Inicializamos los controles */
        editTextRecoveryEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRecoveryEmail);
        editTextRecoveryCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRecoveryCode);
        editTextRecoveryPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRecoveryPassword);
        editTextRecoveryPasswordConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRecoveryPasswordConfirm);
        buttonRecoverySubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecoverySubmit);
        buttonRecoveryCode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecoveryCode);
        buttonRecoveryEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecoveryEmail);
    /* Objeto validador */
    validatorEmail = new Validator(this);
    validatorCode = new Validator(this);
    validatorSubmit = new Validator(this);

    validatorEmail.setValidationListener(new ValidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValidationSucceeded() {
            // Enviar el email
        }

        @Override
        public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
            String message = failedRule.getFailureMessage();
            if (failedView instanceof EditText) {
                if (failedView.getId() == editTextRecoveryEmail.getId()) {
                    failedView.requestFocus();
                    ((EditText) failedView).setError(message);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    validatorCode.setValidationListener(new ValidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValidationSucceeded() {
            // Validar código
        }

        @Override
        public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
            String message = failedRule.getFailureMessage();
            if (failedView instanceof EditText) {
                if (failedView.getId() == editTextRecoveryCode.getId()) {
                    failedView.requestFocus();
                    ((EditText) failedView).setError(message);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    validatorSubmit.setValidationListener(new ValidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValidationSucceeded() {
            // Validar Submit
        }

        @Override
        public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
            String message = failedRule.getFailureMessage();
            if (failedView instanceof EditText) {
                if (failedView.getId() == editTextRecoveryPassword.getId()
                        || failedView.getId() == editTextRecoveryPasswordConfirm.getId()) {
                    failedView.requestFocus();
                    ((EditText) failedView).setError(message);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /* Comportamiento del botón de Registro */
    buttonRecoveryEmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validatorEmail.validate();
        }

    });

    /* Comportamiento del botón de Registro */
    buttonRecoveryCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validatorCode.validate();
        }

    });

    /* Comportamiento del botón de Registro */
    buttonRecoverySubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validatorSubmit.validate();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. You'll need 3 validators in 3 different controller classes to handle this situation.

```
static class EmailController implements ValidationListener {

    @Email
    private EditText mEmailEditText;
    private Button mSubmitButton;

    private Context mContext;
    private Validator mValidator;

    public EmailController(@NonNull EditText emailEditText, @NonNull Button submitButton) {
        mEmailEditText = emailEditText;
        mSubmitButton = submitButton;
        mContext = emailEditText.getContext();

        mValidator = new Validator(this);
        mValidator.setValidationListener(this);

        mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validator.validate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationSucceeded() {
        // Success...
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        // Failure...
    }
}
```

You'll need 2 more of these - one for validation code and the other one for password. If you wish to communicate with your activity, pass it around or implement appropriate listener interfaces.

Consider simplifying your form, if possible.

Comment: How I have to use this Controller class?

Comment: After you find the references to your widgets using `findViewById`, just do a `new EmailController(emailEditText, submitButton);`

Comment: Check this link for a complete working example https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/104#issuecomment-133822417

Comment: Hi, its giving me this error when calling validator.validate();
am really stuck here

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.ValidationContext.setViewRulesMap(java.util.Map)' on a null object reference